# COMPILATION ERROR : During maven build

Tags: java, maven

An error occurred during maven build.

**console log:**

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project isoc: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>
> [ERROR] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7

**environment:**

- Window 10
- Eclipse neon
- Installed JREs(jdk1.8.0_77)
- Execution Environment JavaSE-1.7 (jdk1.8.0_77)

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Please do set eclipse's default installed `jre` to a JDK. In Eclipse go to Window Menu => Preferences => enter search string `jre` in left navigation pane => click on "Installed JREs" in left navigation pane => Click Add and browse to your JDK. => click the checkbox next to the JDK to make it default.

Also, make sure that you have JDK installed on your system

Also  check eclipse run configuration is set to use the default jdk you set up:

> Run Menu => Run Configurations => Select the run config for your project (Maven Build) => Click JRE tab => Under Runtime JRE select "workspace default".